# Xcode 4 beta not working

Tags: xcode, installation, beta, xcode4

I downloaded and installed Xcode 4 Developer Preview 6 (January 10, 2011 /  Build: 4A251a )
After the installation i see my old version 3.2.5

any idea why this is not working ?

cheers endo

EDIT: My solution was to fully uninstall Xcode then install the xcode 4 Developer Preview
`sudo Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all`

Comment: Xcode 4 is under NDA. you should post these questions in the dev forum over apple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried removing the old Xcode before installing the new one? Also, did you move the Developer directory from where it was originally located?

Comment: i'm uninstalling it right now "sudo Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all"

Comment: i'm installing again, but i find it strange, that its only working when uninstall or use an other Folder